# how to add different buttons dynamically

Tags: android, layout, button, dynamic

I have an array of Buttons (different sizes etc) which are configured from and xml file (written by me). I want to add those buttons on the bottom of the screen and when the row of buttons ends, just start a new row and add buttons until the array ends. I want to mention that I do not set the size of the buttons in the xml file so I don't know the size from the beginning. Another problem is that after or before I add the button to the layout programatically with layout.addView(button) the method button.getWidth() returns 0 because the UI elements are not drawn in the UI yet. I also overrided the onLayout() method but still wasn't able to redraw the buttons.

If you have any ideas, please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well you could make the button take the same size using weight property. In that case, decide how many buttons you need in a row and use a for loop to do it accordingly. If you need the width you could use something like

Add this to your onCreate

```
ViewTreeObserver vto        =   layout.getViewTreeObserver();
            vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    You should be able to get the width and height
                    over here.

                    layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }
            });
```

Comment: If this worked for you. Set this as the answer. Or if you got another add that as the answer so this will be removed from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. I overrided the onMeasure() method of the layout containing the buttons.

```
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int specSize =  MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        this.width = specSize;

        specSize =  MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        this.height = specSize;

        //now you can use the sizes before the layout is drawn
        this.webview.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,this.height - this.menuBarHeight) );

        //don't forget for the parent method! 
        //but at the end, after the measures are done
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);   
    }
```